# TCP Reno - Is a timeout guaranteed in this situation (loss of segment in fast retransmit)?

Tags: tcp

In this situation:

[image]

Is there a way for this situation to not end with a timeout? From my understanding, duplicate acks (Acks that require segment #1 to be sent) that are received during fast recovery will only enable me to send new segments, but not segment #1 again - meaning that at the end a timeout will occur.

Is this correct or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you are not overlooking anything.

In your situation, every received ACK, before or after the retransmission of segment 1 will acknowledge segment 0[*] and there is no way for the Reno sender to distinguish between ACKs that were sent before or after the retransmission. The only way to exit fast recovery will be a timeout.

A more advanced TCP sender with timestamps and SACK may be able to employ a heuristic, but not Reno. You might find references in [this section](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3782#section-6) of New Reno RFC helpful.

[*] to be precise it will contain the expected sequence number of segment one

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, there's no timeout - yet. The question isn't very clear, I'm making some assumptions (send window = 5*MSS)

1. sender transmits segments 0-4; segment 1 is lost in transit
2. receiver ACKs segment 0 (alternatively it selectively ACKs 0,2,3,4)
3. sender resends segment 1, advances the window to 1-5, and transmits segment 5; segment 1 is lost again
4. receiver sends duplicate ACK for segment 0 (or selectively ACKs segment 5)
5. sender resends segment 1

If segment 1 is lost yet again and keeps getting lost, there's an eventual timeout for the connection.

Comment: This isn't completely what I meant but anyway - why would the sender resend 1 in step number 5? Wouldn't he transmit 6 instead?

Comment: Segment 5 is the next segment when the window removes the successfully ACKed segment 0 and advances beyond 4. I'm assuming a window of 5*MSS but that isn't clear from the question.

Comment: Thanks,  but I didn't ask why 5 would be transmitted. I asked what would trigger the retransmission of segment 1 in step 5.